# Does the word "THAT" in this sentence need to be replaced by the word "WHEN"? "Not a week goes by that I don’t wish I was never born."

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, that-vs-which

This is a sentence from a person's regret about being born. The sentence is:

**"Not a week goes by THAT I don’t wish I was never born."**

I understand the sentence, but I am not quite sure about the grammar. The word **"THAT**" is describing the word **"a WEEK**", so the word **"THAT"** is functioning as a relative pronoun.

Since he regrets about this life every week, the regret is experienced in or during every week, which requires a relative pronoun **"WHEN",** not **"THAT**", doesn't it?

So, my question is, should the sentence have been as follows:

**"Not a week goes by WHEN I don’t wish I was never born."**

Regards,

Comment: No: however you analyse the _that_ clause, "that" is not a relative pronoun and thus is not anaphoric. The "that" found in relative clauses and declarative content clauses is a subordinator functioning as a meaningless marker of subordination.

Answer (score 1):

> *Not a week goes by* [*THAT I don’t wish I was never born ___*].

That bracketed expression is a relative clause in which "that" is not a relative pronoun but a meaningless subordinator functioning as a marker.

The relativised element is represented by gap '___' (interpreted as "when"), and it's this that has "week" as antecedent.